# External margins of embedded newmdenv environments

Tags: indentation, mdframed, nesting

In the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=red]{tBox}
\newmdenv[leftmargin=1cm,linecolor=blue]{aBox}
\begin{document}
\begin{aBox}\begin{tBox}text\end{tBox}text\end{aBox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the `leftmargin` of the `aBox` environment affects the `leftmargin` of the `tBox` environment: is this expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the package author (Marco Daniel) intended nested `mdframed` environments to work this way, but it seems that the inner environment simply inherits the settings of the outer environment and then adds its own settings on top of that. If you don't want the inner environment to be (additionally) indented, add `leftmargin=0cm` to its specification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[leftmargin=0cm,backgroundcolor=red]{tBox}
\newmdenv[leftmargin=1cm,linecolor=blue]{aBox}
\begin{document}
\begin{aBox}\begin{tBox}text\end{tBox}text\end{aBox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I thought it would be the behaviour by default.

Comment: @pluton: No. `\newmdenv` passes the optional argument to `setkeys` which works also for nested environments.